# Label text isn't updating even though UI thread seems to be responsive

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, javafx-8, tornadofx

I'm building an application with TornadoFX 1.7.11 using Kotlin 1.1.51 on JDK 8u121.

I'm trying to execute a long-running task in a separate thread and show progress in the UI using a progressbar and a label. Strangely, the label isn't updating. I thought that maybe I somehow ran the task on UI thread and it's stuck, but the progressbar works and UI is otherwise responsive (controls work etc.).

[image: Screenshot with progressbar half-filled and console messages showing that message is updated. A red arrow is pointing to a place where label should be, but no text is visible there.]

I've also tried to manually edit the label with ScenicView and it worked. I'm out of ideas, can you guys help?

Here are somewhat simplified code snippets:

MainView.kt

```
class MainView : View("") {
    private val controller: MainController by inject()

    override val root = borderpane {
        bottom(TasksView::class)
    }

    init {
        controller.reloadTranslations().completed.onChange {
            // do some lightweight UI stuff
        }
    }
}
```

MainController.kt

```
class MainController : Controller() {
    private val tasksController: TasksController by inject()

    fun reloadTranslations(): TaskStatus {
        val task = TaskStatus()
        tasksController.tasks.add(task)
        runAsync(task) {
            updateMessage(messages["loadingTranslations"])
            BibxCache.rebuild().subscribe {
                updateMessage(messages["loadingTranslations"] + " " + it.loaded)  // for debugging
                updateProgress(it.loaded.toLong(), it.total.toLong())
            }
        }
        return task
    }

    fun getTranslations() = BibxCache.values.toSortedSet()
}
```

TasksView.kt

```
class TasksView : View() {
    override val root = vbox()

    val controller: TasksController by inject()

    init {
        controller.tasks.onChange {
            root.clear()
            controller.tasks.map { TaskRow(it) }.forEach { root.add(it) }
        }
    }
}

class TaskRow(task: TaskStatus) : HBox() {
    init {
        val progressBar = ProgressBar(task.progress.get())
        progressBar.bind(task.progress)
        val label = Label(task.message.get())
        label.bind(task.message)
        task.message.onChange { println(it) }  // for debugging
        children.addAll(
                progressBar,
                Label(task.message.get())
        )
    }
}
```

TasksController.kt

```
class TasksController : Controller() {
    val tasks: ObservableList<TaskStatus> = FXCollections.observableArrayList()

    init {
        tasks.onChange { change ->
            change.next()
            change.addedSubList.forEach { added ->
                added.completed.onChange {
                    tasks.remove(added)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code isn't runnable, but I created a minimal sample based on these concepts, using a more idiomatic approach.

```
class MainView : View("Tasks") {
    private val mainController: MainController by inject()

    override val root = borderpane {
        setPrefSize(600.0, 400.0)
        top {
            button("Start task").action {
                mainController.reloadTranslations()
            }
        }
        bottom(TasksView::class)
    }
}

class MainController : Controller() {
    private val tasksController: TasksController by inject()

    fun reloadTranslations(): TaskStatus {
        val task = TaskStatus()
        tasksController.tasks.add(task)
        runAsync(task) {
            updateMessage(messages["loadingTranslations"] + " $this...")
            Thread.sleep(Random().nextInt(2000).toLong())
            updateMessage(messages["loadingTranslations"] + " $this - half way")
            updateProgress(50.0, 100.0)
            Thread.sleep(Random().nextInt(2000).toLong())
        }
        return task
    }
}

class TasksView : View() {
    val controller: TasksController by inject()

    override val root = vbox {
        bindChildren(controller.tasks) { task ->
            hbox {
                progressbar(task.progress)
                label(task.message)
            }
        }
    }
}

class TasksController : Controller() {
    val tasks: ObservableList<TaskStatus> = FXCollections.observableArrayList()

    init {
        tasks.onChange { change ->
            change.next()
            change.addedSubList.forEach { added ->
                added.completed.onChangeOnce {
                    tasks.remove(added)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This can also be done with less fanfare, but I don't know the complexity or requirements of your app, so I changed it as little as possible :)

Comment: Thank you! I like your approach, it's concise, readable and works as expected.

Comment: Happy to hear that :))